# How to force Cloud SQL restart

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've seen variants of this question around, but I'm looking for a definitive answer if anyone has one...

We are running a Cloud SQL Postgres instance, and are stuck on restarting the DB after having an export crash out with an unspecified error.

For several hours now our DB has been out of action saying it's restarting.
The options to export, restart, all of that good stuff, are greyed out and unavailable.

There doesn't seem to be a way to force a restart either through the console, or via gcloud command.

Most of the replies I've seen to this question seem to end up with the poster being helped out by Google support. Don't get me wrong, I'd very much appreciate that, but I'd also like to know if there's a way of doing this myself?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the 'force restart' option is not available for 'PostgreSQL' instance.

There may be several reasons behind the 'stuck' stage of an SQL instance. Not every time, 'force restart' option wouldn't resolves the root/actual cause.

However, if you still think this option needs to be included in the 'PostgreSQL' instance, I strongly recommend opening a 'Feature Request' through the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). While opening the 'Feature Request', try to include a bit more details about your use case scenario(with or without an example) as well.